# Problem with a chart with a polyline and a LinearGradientBrush

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a graph with a polyline contained into a canvas. I would like to set the stroke of the polyline starting from a color at the bottom and ending to another color on top. I tried with this xaml:

```
<Polyline StrokeThickness="2">
  <Polyline.Stroke>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,1" EndPoint="0.5,0">
      <GradientStop Color="Blue"  Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="Cyan" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Polyline.Stroke>
</Polyline>
```

In this way it works but the height of the gradient is equal to the height of the polyline. I mean, if I have a polyline which goes from the bottom of the canvas to its top, the gradient is applied over the entire height of the canvas. If I have instead a horizontal polyline, the gradient is applied to its thickness.
I would like to have a gradient height equal to the canvas height, independently from the polyline height.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start and stop of the gradient is given by the `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` properties of the `LinearGradientBrush`. Your example shows values that are inside the `PolyLine` (0.5,1 and 0.5,0). You can have values smaller than 0 or larger than 1 in order to start the gradient before the shape or end after it.

But using relative values may be hard for what you want. Relative values are used because the `MappingMode` property of the `LinearGradientBrush` is not explicitly set. The default value is `RelativeToBoundingBox`, but can be set to `Absolute`.

This way, you can set the `StartPoint` to (0,0) and the `EndPoint` to the width and height of the canvas to get the result you are looking for.